# Can't install Python SDK (Windows 10, python 3.6 , couchbase server 6)

Tags: python-3.x, couchbase

I am using python 3.6 and couchbase server 6 (on Windows 10) . When I am trying to install Python SDK , its failing with pip install couchbase as easy_install couchbase.

```
 For pip install couchbase , I am getting (pasting the error message only)   
::
c:\user\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-s9herosn\couchbase 
 \src\pycbc.h(193): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:   
‘libcouchbase/couchbase.h’: No such file or directory
error: command ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC  
\BIN\cl.exe’ failed with exit status 2

And for easy_install couchbase I am getting (pasting the error message  
only) ::
ERROR:root:{‘ext_modules’:  
[<cmake_build.CMakeExtension(‘couchbase_core._libcouchbase’) at  
0xd02430>]}
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:152 (string):
string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCHALL needs at least 5 arguments total  
to command.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:153 (string):
string sub-command REGEX, mode REPLACE needs at least 6 arguments total to
command.
CMake Error at C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32 
/Lib/site-packages/cmake-3.15.3-py3.6-win32.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-
3.15/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2410 (message):
error: could not find git for clone of libcouchbase_src
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages  
/cmake-3.15.3-py3.6-win32.egg/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.15/Modules 
/ExternalProject.cmake:3204 (_ep_add_download_command)
CMakeLists.txt:305 (ExternalProject_Add)
```